# Compiler optimization: Java bytecode

Tags: java, optimization, compiler-construction, bytecode

I'm currently writing a toy compiler targeting Java bytecode in the translation.

I would like to know if there is some kind of catalog, maybe a summary, of various simple peephole optimizations that can be made in the emitted bytecode before writing the .class file. I actually am aware of some libraries that have this functionality, but I'd like to implement that myself.

Comment: Most of the optimization are not done in the Java compiler but in the runtime. Is your target performance results or performance result without runtime optimizations?

Comment: The real target would be compiler learning. I guess that makes optimizations in compile-time more interesting to me, so I can see what's going on and implement it myself, rather than leaving it to another software.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are aware of Proguard? http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

This is a great bytecode optimizer which implements a lot of optimizations. See the FAQ for a list: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html

- Evaluate constant expressions.
- Remove unnecessary field accesses and method
  calls.
- Remove unnecessary branches.
- Remove unnecessary comparisons and
  instanceof tests.
- Remove unused code
  blocks.
- Merge identical code blocks.
- Reduce variable allocation.
- Remove
  write-only fields and unused method
  parameters.
- Inline constant fields,
  method parameters, and return values.
- Inline methods that are short or only
  called once.
- Simplify tail recursion
  calls.
- Merge classes and interfaces.
- Make methods private, static, and
  final when possible.
- Make classes
  static and final when possible.
- Replace interfaces that have single
  implementations.
- Perform over 200
  peephole optimizations, like
  replacing ...*2 by ...<<1.
- Optionally
  remove logging code.

I'm sure you can further look into the source code to understand how they are implemented.

Comment: IS there a .NET version perhaps?

Comment: Merge classes and interfaces: How does the compiler know that it can collapse a type hierarchy? It can only be sure about private interfaces.

Comment: In Java, compilation "really" happens at runtime: this is what the JIT does inside the JVM. The javac compiler is just a source to bytecode translator, and is required to emit certain bytecode for given source. So Proguard does part of what JIT does, not what javac does, in the Java ecosystem.

Comment: Do any of the standard Java tools, seven years on, do any of these optimizations?

Comment: Yes, the JIT. It always did, and is constantly being optimized.

Comment: @JesseTG Hey there, I also have the similar confusion. So my goal is to find a way to optimize the Java bytecode **before** runtime. I am aware that JIT can do lots of runtime optimization, but I want to optimize bytecode before getting it executed in JIT. Do you happen to know a good tool that fits this demand?

Comment: @JesseTG, right now what I am looking at is to first convert bytecode to LLVM IR, then leverage optimization passes there. But this does not work out well; one thing is that this translation itself is hard, and I somehow find that optimization passes in LLVM do not take Java/JVM-language into consideration and therefore the optimization chance is slim.