# How does java optimisation? Example code

Tags: java, compilation, bytecode, compiler-optimization

Consider this small class:

```
public class Example {
  public int plus(int a){
    int b;
    b = 1;
    return b+a;
  }
}
```

javap says:

```
public int plus(int);
  descriptor: (I)I
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=2, locals=3, args_size=2
     0: iconst_1
     1: istore_2
     2: iload_2
     3: iload_1
     4: iadd
     5: ireturn
  LineNumberTable:
    line 4: 0
    line 5: 2
```

I don't understand why we need line 1&2?

I heard that the Java Runtime environment counts function calls and compiles functions if they exceed a certain number of calls.

Does that mean that the Java compiler leaves all optimisation to the byte code compiler? E.g. Java programs start slow and become faster by time?

Please explain!

Comment: Down voters please leave a comment, I don't see whats wrong, this question doesn't seem off-topic to me. I'm yet sorry for bad hair days ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does java bytecode "store" often followed by "load"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779752/why-does-java-bytecode-store-often-followed-by-load)

Comment: You're right! Beside of that I asked some additional sub questions.
Actually also duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981460/optimization-by-java-compiler?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are looking at the output of the bytecode compiler.  Typical Java bytecode compilers do very little optimization.  The heavy-weight optimization is done by the JIT compiler ... at runtime.

So what you see displayed by `javap -c` is unoptimized bytecodes.

> I don't understand why we need line 1&2?

You are looking at unoptimized bytecodes.  The first 2 instructions assign `1` to the local variable `b`.  We can see that the local variable could easily be optimized away.  However the bytecode compler (`javac`) doesn't bother.

> I heard that the Java Runtime environment counts function calls and compiles functions if they exceed a certain number of calls.

That's how a typical Hotspot JVM works.

> Does that mean that the Java compiler leaves all optimisation to the byte code compiler?

No.  It is the JIT compiler that does the runtime compilation and the associated optimization.

The bytecode compiler compiles Java source code to bytecodes.  The JIT compiler compiles bytecodes to native code ... at runtime.

> E.g. Java programs start slow and become faster by time?

That is correct.  The initial bytecode interpretation phase and the JIT compilation are part of what is referred to as "JVM warmup".

---

(As requested ...)

The reasons that the bytecode compiler doesn't optimize include:

- because the JIT compiler *does* optimize (so it would be wasted effort),
- because optimizing the bytecodes *could* make it harder to optimize in the JIT compiler ("clever" code is harder to optimize than simple code), and
- because non-optimized byte codes make it easier for a profiler or debugger to relate code back to source code lines.

And the reasons the the JIT compiler does the optimization include:

- because it needs to be done in the step that generates native code to achieve best results,
- because it is platform dependent (e.g. the optimal code depends on the target instruction set, and potentially on things like memory cache sizes, number of cores and so on), and
- because it allow you to optimize based on the *observed* behavior of the code as it is executing (e.g. improved branch prediction).

Finally, JIT compilation fits in well with Java's late binding model.

Comment: Also note that leaving the local variables unoptimized makes debugging easier.

Comment: Actually I meant the JIT compiler when I spoke about the "byte code compiler". What is the correct term for the compiler creating class-files from my java files? I'd edit this in my question.
@Antimony Thank you for pointing this out. Seems reasonable.

Comment: @StephenC I'll accept your answer as this was what I actually wanted to know. Thank you! Still, if you have some time later to add some of those many reasons you didn't add, I'd be very grateful.