# Compiling without assertions

Tags: java, performance, assert

I know assertions can be enabled/disabled at runtime for debugging and production, respectively. However I found that assertions also increase the size of the generated binary (about 100-200 bytes in the example below).

In C and C++, we can do this at compile time by having `#define NDEBUG` before `#include <assert.h>`.

Is there any way for the Java compiler to automatically do this? I'd like to leave them in the source code for debugging purposes later on. But I also don't want the resultant binary to be any larger than necessary (we have a size limit as design requirement).

C code:

```
//#define NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>

int main(void) {
    assert(0); // +200 bytes without NDEBUG, 0 with NDEBUG
    return 0;
}
```

Java code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assert(System.nanoTime()==0); // increases binary size by about 200 bytes
    }
}
```

---

In response to bn.'s answer:

```
public class Test2 {
    public static final boolean assertions = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(assertions) {
            assert(System.nanoTime()==0);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: In fact, it seems to me that this enabling/disabling is a more useful compile-time feature than run-time. I mean, how many end users will enable them? As far as a programmer is concerned during the debug process, he/she will likely be recompiling code anyways.

Comment: That doesn't prove that every assert costs 200 bytes, only that one does.

Comment: @EJP: For sure. What I meant was that there is a non-negligable increase caused by asserts as a whole. The precise amount certainly depends on the complexity of the statement.

Comment: If you bother with such things, you are with the wrong language.

Comment: Did you try `public **final** static boolean assertions = false;`?

Comment: If all else fails, you could modify your build process to run `cpp` over your Java files. Hacky, but it should get the job done.

Comment: @MiserableVariable: Aha, that did it. There was a small 50 byte overhead when I tried it. However that can probably be attributed to having to define the `assertions` variable.

Comment: Binary size is relatively cheap, and the JIT eliminates these at class-load time anyway.  What's the point?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, The point is Java also compiles to phone apps and webapplets, not just desktop apps. Java is also meant to run on smartcards, TV, automobiles, PDAs, discplayers, embedded devices, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would not do the following because of the complexity added to the source code but javac generated the exact same intermediate code for `main`  in the following two fragments:

**conditional asserts**

```
class C {
    public final static boolean assertions = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(assertions) {
            assert(System.nanoTime()==0);
        }
    }
}
```

**no asserts**

```
class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

**compiled code**

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: return        
    LineNumberTable:
      line 3: 0
```

**EDIT**

> In fact, it seems to me that this enabling/disabling is a more useful
>   compile-time feature than run-time. I mean, how many end users will
>   enable them?

Its not end users that enable them, it is the customer support that tells the end user to enable them. I do wish though they were enabled, not disabled, by default.

Comment: Perfect thanks! I agree that it's not a very elegant solution but it does address my question.

Comment: It seems that if you put your `public final static boolean assertions = false;` variable on a separated class, so that you could use asserts all over your code and just change the flag on one place, you will need to recompile the whole source if that is changed (and that is desirable, since you want the variable wiped from your compiled code).

Comment: @Ivella this is because the compiler inlines public static finals.

Comment: @MiserableVariable, Exactly, so your answer doesn't prove anything, since we can get the same intermediate code when we use public static final *simple-if-else* **no-assert**.

Comment: @Pacerier I am afraid I don't understand your comment. My answer shows that using conditional asserts will in some cases result in intermediate code that is not bigger than code that does not have asserts. On the other hand, this is an old discussion so it is likely I am missing some important observation. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: > I do wish though they were enabled, not disabled, by default.                            Oh yes, oh yes!  IMHO, disabling by default is THE big design mistake of Java assertions. It reduces the usefulness of the feature to about 10%.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible as a built in compilation step.  You can however, do this by adding conditional blocks around your assertions.

See the article ["Removing all Trace of Assertions from Class Files"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#usage-adv-removing) for more information.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but it actually increased the binary even more by another 50 bytes.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense since the compiler should remove the statements altogether since it is now unreachable.

Comment: @Robin if OP uses `final` it will reduce the size.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Are you sure? `javac` skips lots of sensible optimizations, possible at compile time, just because it assumes the runtime optimizer will take care of it. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680024/compiler-optimization-java-bytecode/1680212#comment13213854_1680212).

Comment: @bn. Your link (the meat of the answer) is gone.