# Does dynamically generated java byte-code need any optimization?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I did some java byte code generation using ASM.
By walking through some sort of AST of some kind of small DSL in visitor pattern.
And I'm worrying about the generated byte code is too 'straightforward', that is, without any 'compile-time optimization'.
Although in my case, that could be ok if the generated byte code is not optimized, still I can't help to ask: is there a need for those projects which generate byte code at runtime to do bytecode optimization?
I know the fact that for jvm, most of the 'optimization' work is done while the program is running, by jit compilation. So the bytecode optimization at compile time may effect little.
But, really? Is it absolutely meaningless to do bytecode optimization for the bytecode generated on the fly? Is there any one to share some experience about the difference, mainly in runtime performance, between bytecodes with and without any form of optimization?

Comment: You could try hardcoding an example and racing it against your bytecode generator...

Comment: If your piece of code is not run very often, it won't be optimised by the JIT, but it does not matter because it does not run very often. And if it does run often, it will be optimised. Everybody's happy.

Comment: Please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1680212/655756. In other words, you may do further optimizations, but it's not necessary as usually those optimizations look more like "cosmetic" ones.

Comment: @assylias yes, u r right,but what I seriously care about is, could the bytecode optimized by compile time + jit outperform which that only optimized by jit?

Comment: @n1ckolas ah.., I see, you mean it wouldn't make much difference if do  the optimization or not. Because the jit compiling could make all bytecodes very efficient eventually, no matter how verbose the original bytecode can be. And thanks, proguard may be a nice tool.

Comment: @pf_miles exactly, I wouldn't say better :)

Comment: Do you have any performance problems with running the generated bytecode? I presume not. Hence, question is irrelevant.

Comment: @Ingo No, I'm not facing any performance problems with running the 'straightforward' bytecode. I just be curious to ask this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know at least one JVM based language, which share remain nameless, is slow as hell. It could have used some compile time optimization.

Javac and JVM are analyzing roughly the same programming model, therefore any optimization techniques that Javac can employ can be employed by JVM too. Then there is not much point for Javac to duplicate the work. Actually it's probably preferred that Javac leaves as much structure of the source code as possible so JVM can better reason about the code.

That doesn't apply if the source language is not a Java-ish language.

Think about this, CPU does a lot of wonderful optimization too, so why does JVM need to do any optimization? Why not leave it all to CPU. Because CPU and JVM are analyzing very different code. CPU is analyzing an arbitrary sequence of machine instructions(though it can make assumptions based on common behaviors of high level languages). JVM is analyzing a very specific, much higher level language, JVM can reason and transform the code based on knowledges that are almost impossible for CPU to discover from the machine instructions.

Back to your case, it is possible that, you (as the compiler) knows a lot better about your even-higher-level source language, you can perform transformations that are impossible by JVM.

Comment: Great explanation! I think I understood your point, it makes me sobering. So, if my DSL introduces a higher programming model —— boolean logic in some form of 'rule engine' for example, I could do some optimizations in boolean logic theory, like 'gate logic optimization'. But if my DSL is just another encapsulated imperative  programming language, just like java, there's no need to do any optimization, right?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not necessary.

If you look at Javac's output, it does virtually no compile time optimization at all. And thanks to Hotspot's JIT, it is difficult to tell what impact changing the bytecode will have on optimization anyway. It's best not to worry about such things unless you can prove there's a real bottleneck and have the time to investigate it.